# How to convert GMT+5.5 to normal time in php

Tags: php

I Have wrote below code which gives me UTC time (default time zone is "UTC")
How to convert UTC time to GMT+5.5

```
$todaysDate= date("Y-m-d-h-i-a");                                        
list($year,$month,$day,$hour,$minute,$meridian) = explode('-',$todaysDate);
$dtime = mktime($hour,$minute, 0, $month, $day, $year);
$dtime = $dtime + ($_SESSION['user_time_zone_offset'] * 60 * 60);
$dtime = date("H:i a", $dtime);                  
echo $dtime;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
```

It should work

Answer (score 0):

for GMT+5.5, better to use like below code in your php file .........

```
<?php session_start();
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
    $todaysDate= date("Y-m-d-h-i-a");                                        
    list($year,$month,$day,$hour,$minute,$meridian) = explode('-',$todaysDate);
    $dtime = mktime($hour,$minute, 0, $month, $day, $year);
    //$dtime = $dtime + ($_SESSION['user_time_zone_offset'] * 60 * 60);
    $dtime = date("H:i a", $dtime);                  
    echo $dtime;
?>
```

<< Out put gives Indian current time >>
And please search similar questions before posting new question....